# Bayesian analysis example with convergence under Gibbs but not Metropolis-Hastings

Tags: bayesian, metropolis-hastings, gibbs

Having a conceptual understanding of algorithms such as Metropolis-Hastings, Gibbs and Hamiltonian Monte Carlo can provide ideas of remediation to apply when models do not converge. This question focuses on Metropolis-Hastings and Gibbs, I had previously thought that sampler affected efficiency more than convergence. Gibbs does not seem to have superseded Metropolis-Hastings so they must each have relative benefits.

https://www.stata.com/features/overview/gelman-rubin-convergence-diagnostic/ gives an example of a linear regression with non-convergence under Metropolis-Hastings but an excellent convergence under Gibbs sampling.

“The default adaptive Metropolis–Hastings used by bayes: and bayesmh may suffer from low efficiency in the presence of many highly correlated model parameters [which is the case here]. In our example, the default priors used by bayes: regress—normal for coefficients and inverse gamma for the variance—allow us to use a more efficient Gibbs sampling.”.

How do these default priors allow Gibbs?

I understand the basic idea of Metropolis-Hastings and Gibbs, but currently not enough to understand how they could alter convergence of the example linear regression with highly correlated independent variables. What is the reason for this difference in convergence between the two sampling methods?

Comment: Priors that lead to close form standard conditional distributions allow for Gibbs. The fact that one "default" Metropolis-Hastings implementation is inefficient does not mean that all Metropolis-Hastings implementations will fail.

Comment: @Xi’an “priors that lead to close form standard conditional distributions”, does “lead to” mean to the posterior? If so, this would be dependent on the likelihood also? Would another way of performing non-convergence remediation in the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm would be to say change the random seed, increase the number of chains, run the sampler over more iterations, things like this?

Comment: yes, closed form posterior distributions depend on appropriate choice of prior for a specific likelihood. To improve MH convergence I would first look to see if my model is well specified (with my choice of priors), then I would try various proposal distributions, then I would increase iterations

Comment: @bdeonovic could “well specified” be rephrased as checking the priors will theoretically converge? Trying various proposal distributions means varying the priors?

Comment: by "well specified" I mean things like is the model identifiable, do the priors provide the correct bounds on the variables. For MH by proposal distribution I mean how is the next MCMC sample proposed. Standard MH samples a proposal from a normal distribution centered at the previous proposal. Is this a good choice? what shoudl the variance be? etc.

Comment: If possible though I would **highly recommend** using a HMC type of sampler like NUTS which takes advantage of gradients of the posterior.

Comment: I also just looked at the stata example you provided. I think in that particular case it would benefit a lot from a QR reparameterization. see e.g. (https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_24/stan-users-guide/QR-reparameterization-section.html)

Comment: @bdeonovic the HMC / NUTS sampler is an option, maybe the default, of Stan; the relative benefits of samplers seems more useful knowledge than I had previously thought. Section 24.7 of the Stan user guide: “In some cases, reparameterization can dramatically increase effective sample size for the same number of iterations or even make programs that would not converge well behaved.”.

Comment: You conflate two ideas in that last comment: samplers and model parameterizations. Yes, different samplers can have vastly different sampling efficiencies (as your MH vs Gibbs example shows), and also orthogonal to that point, the parameterization used for a particular model can also impact sampling efficiency as pointed out in that Stan documentation on the QR parameterization for linear regression models.

Comment: @SingleMalt "Gibbs does not seem to have superseded Metropolis-Hastings so they must each have relative benefits". MH algorithm is more general than Gibbs one. So we can find examples where MH work and Gibbs not. The opposite sound me strange even if MH can be less efficient in some cases.